Analog PID - Integrator reset
I am trying to design an analog PID, in this circuit, the integrator has an Integral clear button. After some reading I understand (correct me if I am wrong) that when the op-amp saturates, or equivalently when the capacitor is fully charged, the integrator part of the PID does not work properly anymore. To solve this problem, one needs to discharge the capacitor. Here this is done by offering a direct discharge path to the output via a button.

Q1: Is this kind of design still relevant? I think there are PIDs everywhere but I find it hard to believe that there has to be someone switching a button frequently for their servoing to work?
Q2: Is there another solution ? For example is there a standard circuit where this clearing happens automatically?
Q3: If I use a integrator with a limited DC gain (see picture below) , do I still need this clearing feature, as there is always a DC path for the discharge of the capacitor?


You can have a look at the PID slides of my APEC 2021 seminar (starting on 52) in which I show how to build an anti-windup circuit and how it limits the recovery time of an op-amp-based PID.


Q1: Is this kind of design still relevant? I think there are PIDs everywhere but I find it hard to believe that there has to be someone switching a button frequently for their servoing to work?

This design is no longer relevant beyond academic purposes. In practice, we would use a MCU or DSP. Not only will these devices handle the "push the reset button in firmware", but also gives the designer extreme flexibility in the tuning among other advanced tricks that can't be realized with an analog (opamp) PID controller. Some of these tricks include gain scheduling where the gain can change both dynamically in time and with different operating points. Another trick is you can completely compensate for non-linearities in the control loop due to the process being controlled. Both of these tricks can't be realized with the basic analog PID due to having a fixed gain and no configurability. So a compromise always has to be made.

Q2: Is there another solution ? For example is there a standard circuit where this clearing happens automatically?

It can be designed such that the resetting happens automatically - you can put an anolog switch across the cap and trigger the reset with external circuitry. But you wouldn't want to do that as it adds a transient in your control loop. This would cause a disturbance that is not due to a perturbation (the reason to have a control loop in the first place) that has to settle back to equilibrium. The idea is to design the solution so that saturation never occurs over the whole operating regime.

Q3: If I use a integrator with a limited DC gain (see picture below) , do I still need this clearing feature, as there is always a DC path for the discharge of the capacitor?

The lower the resistor, the greater loss in DC gain. This is not desirable from a control stand point - at best, you will always have a steady-state error. At worst, you compromised the loop performance to a point that renders your process uncontrollable.

PIDs are of course still used. Sometimes the circuit differs, but they all have similar elements. You are correct -- if the opamp saturates, then the 'I' portion becomes zero (so do all the other portions -- the opamp output is not dependent on the input while it is saturated).
If the system allows the opamp to saturate, then it is not controlling the loop, and information is lost -- or there is a failure somewhere. Resetting the C may allow the system to restart. Of course you could clear it be using a transistor across the capacitor too. Remember that clearing it also loses information -- think of it as a 2nd input (from the user, not the system under control); you can't just arbitrarily clear the capacitor and have the system behave the same.
Even if you limit the gain, the C can still saturate.
Some PID systems have what is called 'anti-windup' -- where the 'I' portion deliberately is limited. This is because in an ideal system, the 'I' term 'remembers' all past history and this is used to set the average error to zero. This will also require that the output can temporarily exceed the steady-state value if it had ever had been below the value. This may be undesirable. Consider a car's speed control; you don't really want to exceed the set point if the vehicle temporarily slowed down -- speed limits aren't average speeds, but instantaneous speeds.
